# Using a Generic Gamepad for Batman Arkham Asylum (or PS3 controller)

Tags: pc, controllers, batman-arkham-asylum

I need some help setting up my PC to play Arkham Asylum. It was the one Arkham game I have yet to play (minus Knight but I'm no time traveller :P) and I got it on PC via a Steam Sale ($5 was a bargin!)

The problem is I want to use my generic gamepad. I have a few of them for game development so it seems daft to buy an X360 controller for one game. But after half an hour of searching via Google, I can't find a suitable tutorial.

Can anyone help me with this? I do have a PS3 controller if that makes setting controller-based gameplay easier.

Thanks to any who can help!

EDIT: Where in the game is the ability to change controller methods? I am looking for anything to do with the so-called "X360 controller" section but I can't find it.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141866/how-can-i-use-any-game-controller-on-my-pc-with-batman-arkham-origins is about a different game (Origins rather than Asylum) but the first answer may still be relevant.

Comment: I got the x360. I have set it up to what it is expected. But now I can't find the option to switch between keyboard and controller. Any help? Any pictures?

Comment: Does that game-pad comes with a disk or joystick drivers?

Comment: It was plug-and-play. It installed itself and it has been working ever since.

Comment: Your question is poor - It does not state what about the controller isn't working and the unspecific "X360 controller section" your edit refers to is without context. You should be able to edit the config file for the game's controls - That's what I did for my Logitech which presented with control-stick inversion and confusing button mapping. I'll see if I can pull the relevant references, but I won't be sure it will help you if I don't know what's not working about your current setup.

Comment: Sorry this is all new to me using gamepads.

Right now I have diagnosed the situation down to the fact that the gamepad isn't working with the X360ce program I was suggested. I have used the troubleshoot methods given in the manual for X360ce

I am using a Speedlink Strike Gamepad with Windows 8.

Comment: I would rather not have to troubleshoot X360ce if I can avoid it because that would involve additional research and testing. I'd rather get you playing the game as soon as possible with what I already know about configuring controller input for this game. Does the game respond to your controller at all? With x360ce? Without X360ce? If it does respond, in what way is it not working? Describing the problem in better detail is helpful. If you'd rather use a Dualshock3, MotionJoy is the program to use (http://www.hardcoreware.net/how-to-use-a-ps3-controller-in-windows-8/)

Comment: It doesn't respond to the game at all. With out without the x360ce. But does work in the Control-Panel so it clearly isn't a gamepad issue.

I tried MotionJoy and it didn't work either. Same situation.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't install all the drivers. You should get some response, even if it's the wrong one. Windows will probably install some default drivers when you connect your controllers, but aside from adding the device to Game Controllers in the device manager, they aren't terribly useful. You need to download and install the appropriate drivers. This goes for either controller http://www.speedlink.com/?p=2&cat=3132&pid=23402&paus=1 for your speedlink and MotionJoy's DS3 tool's drivers or the ones from the guide I linked before should give you *some* response.

Comment: I highly recommend going with MotioninJoy because it will take care of the drivers, supports rumble, and does 1:1 x360 controller support. Using the most recent release, I find the local mode a bit wonky and the ads unwanted, but since I spend next to no time in the interface, it doesn't matter. Once the drivers are installed, the profiles page of MotioninJoy should list your Dualshock 3/sixaxis in the Connected game controller(s). If it doesn't, your Motioninjoy drivers didn't take. Once you change the profile, click enable and it will change the driver for you.